# Conditional Sum in R - Calculating 2 different sums by calling sum function once

Tags: r

I want to calculate the sum of numbers in a vector which are less than 10 and count the number of occurrences of such numbers in R.

For that I have written the following code:

```
sum = sum(numbers[which(numbers<=10)])
 count = sum(numbers<=10)
```

Is there any way to do merge these statements? Rather than call the function sum twice?

Comment: When you say 'list', do you actually mean 'vector'?

Comment: @tospig Yes I meant vector

Comment: You can create your own custom function to do both calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own function:

```
sum_occ <- function(x) {c(sum = sum(x), occ = length(x))}
```

and applied it on `numbers[which(numbers <= 10)]`. It calls `sum` once, `length` once, and of course `which` once when you call the function with the needed subset.

**example**

```
set.seed(123)
numbers <- sample(1:20, 20, replace=T)
> sum_occ(numbers[which(numbers <= 10)])
#sum occ 
# 52   9
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit Baroque but this will only call `sum` (and `which`) once and still use the value twice:

```
numbers <- 10:1
mapply(do.call, c( function(x){sum(numbers[x])}, #first function
                   length),                      # count of numbers <5
                MoreArgs=list(list(which(numbers<5) )) )
#[1] 10  4
```